# Manual fsck every day

Tags: boot, server, lvm, fsck

I have the latest ubuntu distro on a server which I run 24/7. About once a day the server will just appear to be offline, my plex goes down and when I try to SSH in, I just get connection refused.

Every time it randomly does this, i try to power cycle (which doesn’t help) and I have to plug in a monitor and keyboard to which I’m met with

```
(Initramfs): /dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
  Inodes that were a part of a corrupted orphan linked lost found.
  /dev/sda1 : UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck manually.(I.e .,
  without -a or -p options). fsck exited with status code 4. The root
  filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck
```

I do a manual fcsk  `fcsk -yf /dev/sda1` and it fixes the issue, I can boot back normally.

Give it roughly 8-10 hours and it does the exact same thing, no plex, ssh connection refused and I’m back to being asked to manually fcsk.

What’s my issue here ? What am I doing incorrectly ?

Comment: Sounds like you might have a hardware issue going on with your system.  It sounds like your system is rebooting at a random time then getting stuck at needing the fsck.  You might want to check your drive for loose cables, etc.  I would recommend getting locking SATA cables if you don't have them as they can come loose from fan and drive vibrations.  After I replaced all my SATA cables with locking ones I have never had an issue arise of data errors due to loose cables. Also, look at RAM for possible bad memory.

Comment: I haven’t checked my ram, but I have reseated my hdd cables multiple times the past few times

Comment: If you can do graphical like `ssh -Y server` and run `gnome-logs` you might see pending unreadable sectors on the drive or maybe look at the SMART data `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`.  From what you're describing it doesn't sound like anything that software can fix.  It could be a failing drive.  Some hardware failures can be a pain to find on system if they are not bluntly obvious.

Comment: Latest is not a version of Ubuntu. It could be 22.10 it could be 22.04 and what about later when someone reads this. Please give accurate info in the question.

Comment: I have figured out my HDD is failing and that is causing the issue. I don't know 100% what's going on, but there is no smart data to be read from the HDD. Any program I use to diagnose it, only shows the HDD metadata (model number, SN ect) but no other data